# Is there a way to reduce RAM usage by downsampling a large numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a fairly large matrix of the shape (80000, 4), it contains a lot of data, most of which I don't need.

Part of my process involves calculating a pairwise distance matrix, and this process is O(n^2) for the number of rows, so I can reduce processing time a lot by downsampling

I have tried using the numpy.linspace method like so:

```
downsample_factor = np.linspace(0, large_matrix.shape[0]-1, 20000, dtype=int)
large_matrix = large_matrix[downsample_factor, :]
```

In this example `large_matrix` is of shape (80000,4) and I'm downsampling it to around (20000,4)

This code successfully reduces the size of `large_matrix` but doesn't actually free up memory.

Is there another way to free up RAM by downsampling a large array?

EDIT:

The program receives `Killed` messages when it runs out of RAM. I noticed that large arrays were getting `Killed` messages even after downsampling, whereas arrays that were small to begin with did not get killed.

Comment: How are you determining that you aren't freeing up memory? Python itself most likely will not return memory to the operating system, but *can* reuse memory previously used by `large_matrix` should it need more memory, rather than requesting more from the OS.

Comment: @chepner Basically the code works when the array has less than 25000 rows, and fails when its higher. When I watch the RAM usage with HTOP it appears to be the same after downsampling `large_matrix`. I assumed that since it was still getting `killed` messages after downsampling, that the memory had not actually been freed, even though the array was physically smaller

Comment: So, `large_matrix[downsample_factor, :]` creates a *view* of the array, so the underlying buffer won't get freed, I believe. Try to make a `.copy`. Even if it is freed, this might not get reclaimed by the OS and reflected in top, but should be free from the POV of the process.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga as `downsample_factor` is an array, not a slice it entails advanced indexing which will make a copy.

Comment: @PaulPanzer you are right.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you may still have a point, though. A_toaster, are you sure there are no views into the original array still lingering? Any of those would keep the large array alive. For example, if your script contained a line like `first_row = large_matrix[0]` then `large_matrix` would never get freed as long as a reference to `first_row` was still in scope.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I just ran the code with your idea by using: `large_matrix = np.copy(large_matrix[downsample,:]), and it seemed to work even though `large_matrix.shape` was >100000. 

Perhaps I inadvertently removed references to `large_matrix` by doing this?

Comment: How about `large_matrix[::4,:].copy()`?  A view slice every 4th, with an optional copy.-